# Playa with Matrix field loop breaking on different environment

Tags: matrix, playa

Ok guys, I have both latest versions of Matrix and Playa. I'm doing my whole build locally but when I pushed to my production server I'm having an issue. What I have is...

A group of Home types that show on a home type page. the channel for "hometypes" is what I'm using for my playa selection on the "MyHomes" page. so basically my loop looks like this...

```
{houses}
                    {house_slideshow}
                    <div class="slide rsContent">
                        <img class="rsImg" src="{image}" />
                    </div>
                    {/house_slideshow}
                    {house_title}
                    <h3>Description</h3>
                    {description}
                        {feature_list}
                        <li>{feature}</li>
                        {/feature_list} 
    {/houses}
```

Obviously without most of the html. "house_slideshow" and "feature_list" are matrix fields in the "hometypes" channel. the issue is that the loop breaks if I include these. If I were to remove the two matrix loops it would work fine. Basically matrix fields won't work in my playa loop.

Remember, this works perfectly fine locally just not remotely on a server.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is def. related to PHP version 5.4.1 and EE version < 2.6 not sure if there's a fix or not?